# How to do an If Statement that would be the equivalent to "If something is not X then"

Tags: if-statement, vb6

I'm a beginner in programming and have a question about making an If Statement in VB6.

I am doing a program which needs "If length of text field is not 1 then..." but I can't find how to do that, I only know how to do "If length of text field is 1 then..."

So, how would I reverse this:

```
If Len(text) = 1 Then
```

to it NOT being 1

Comment: The MSDN VB6 reference, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

It is

```
If Len(text) <> 1 Then
```

`<>` is inequality operator.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
If Len(text) <> 1 Then
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cey92b0t.aspx

The operator you're looking for is: `If Len(text) <> 1`

Side-note: you could have found that yourself with a 3-second google for visual basic 6 not equals.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the **Not** operator

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim intA As Integer, intB As Integer
  intA = 1
  intB = 2
  If intA = intB Then Print "equal"
  If intA <> intB Then Print "un-equal"
  If Not (intA = intB) Then Print "not equal"
End Sub
```